# onkeyup, get value from textbox, update another textbox, not working

Tags: javascript

Here is the javascript:

```
function changeText(containerId) {
    var datatext = document.getElementById('masterText').value;
    var collection = document.getElementById(containerId).getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for (var x = 0; x < collection.length; x++) {
        if (collection[x].type.toUpperCase() == 'TEXTBOX')
            collection[x].value = datatext;
    }
}
```

and this is the html

```
<input id="masterText" type="textbox" onkeyup="changeText('divGrid')"><br />

<div id="divGrid">
<input type="textbox"><br />
<input type="textbox"><br />
<input type="textbox"><br />
<input type="textbox"><br />
</div>
```

Suppose that all the textbox's value will change, but it is not. Do you know what is the error?

Comment: you need a # sign in front of the selector `changeText('divGrid')`

Comment: there is no `<input type="textbox">`, it's technically `<input type="text">`

Comment: @Shanimal no, you don't. You only need that for jQuery selectors, CSS selectors, and `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll`. `getElementById` just takes the id

Comment: fwiw, any unknown type reverts to text

Comment: sorry, I've been looking at jquery code all day

Comment: do capital letters for `getElementsByTagName` work? You should try lowercase, just to make sure

Comment: @Markasoftware It works now when I change 'textbox' to 'text'. You may repost it as answer :)

Comment: why yes, it does, in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/xakoxeyi/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, `textbox` is not a valid `type` for `<input>` elements. Although unknown types default to `text`, it might have somehow messed up the js (maybe the type property doesn't work right with unknown types), and changing it to just `text` seems to work fine, as you can see in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/xakoxeyi/1/

My best guess at *why* this is happening is that using `element.type` doesn't work right with unknown types, so it doesn't have the value `textbox`, even though that's what html says. The best way to fix this is to change everything to `text` instead (as I said above), but another great way is to, instead of using `collection[x].type`, to use `collection[x].getAttribute('type')`, as using `getAttribute` always gives you what's in the HTML attribute

Comment: *getAttribute* should only be used where the attribute value is required (which is rarely), it is also inconsistent between browsers. The related property should nearly always be used as it is more reliable. In this case, the OP should use a valid value for *type* and use direct property access.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on what Markasoftware said:

Had you chosen to get the attribute `type`, using `getAttribute`, your code would have worked.

```
function changeText(containerId) {
    var datatext = document.getElementById('masterText').value;
    var collection = document.getElementById(containerId).getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
    for (var x = 0; x < collection.length; x++) {
        if (collection[x].getAttribute('type').toUpperCase() == 'TEXTBOX') {
            collection[x].value = datatext;
        }
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MSTUe/

So, my guess is that behind the scenes, an unknown type gets set as a `text` input, however you can still query an input with `textbox`, if needed. Probably for those awesomely new (but poorly supported) HTML5 inputs (like color, datetime-local, week, etc.) that a browser may not support.